# Migrate field type from text to keyword on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

When I want to change the type of a field from text to keyword with this commande :

```
PUT indexStat/_mapping/StatCateg
{
  "StatCateg":{
    "properties": {
      "nom_categorie": {
        "type":"keyword","index": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have this message :

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "mapper [nom_categorie] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [keyword]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "mapper [nom_categorie] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [keyword]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 26):

OK finaly i see in the doc that it's not possible to change data type of a field :

> Updating existing mappings
>
> Other than where documented, existing type and field mappings cannot
>   be updated. Changing the mapping would mean invalidating already
>   indexed documents. Instead, you should create a new index with the
>   correct mappings and reindex your data into that index.

So the only solution is to :

- Recreate a new index with good data types
- Reindex the data with the **Reindex API**

Comment: This is one of the scenarios where index aliases are useful: you code against an alias and you can change the actual index it points to with no downtime.
If you code to actual indices you're either forced to change the index name in the app code, or reindex twice just to get to the original index name.

Answer (score 21):

Changing the data types (mappings) of an existing index is **not supported**. in order to do so, create a new index with the correct types (mappings) and `reindex` your data.

Elastic **[blogpost](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime)** about doing this and recommend using a best-practice approach of aliasing your index.

---

### If you DO NOT  have an aliased index

These are the steps required, the next time will be easier with no downtime

1. Get current mapping of `StatCateg`
2. Create a new index `StatCateg_v1` with the correct mappings
3. Reindex from `StatCateg` to `StatCateg_v1`
4. Delete the old index `StatCateg`
5. Create an alias `StatCateg_v1` -> `StatCateg` (so that on next time this will be easier to do without downtime)

**Example snippet (in python):**

```
import requests

current_index_name = 'StatCateg'
new_index_name = 'StatCateg-v1'
base_url = 'https://...'
mapping_changes = {
    "nom_categorie": {"type": "keyword"}
}

# ------------------------------------------------
# Get current mapping
r = requests.get('{base_url}/{index_name}'.format(base_url=base_url, index_name=current_index_name))
r.raise_for_status()
content = r.json()
mappings = content[current_index_name]['mappings']
mappings['properties'].update(mapping_changes)

# ------------------------------------------------
# Create a new index with the correct mappings
r = requests.put('{base_url}/{index_name}'.format(base_url=base_url, index_name=new_index_name), json={
    'mappings': mappings
})
r.raise_for_status()

# ------------------------------------------------
# Reindex
r = requests.post('{base_url}/_reindex'.format(base_url=base_url), json={
    "source": {
        "index": current_index_name
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": new_index_name
    }
})
r.raise_for_status()

# ------------------------------------------------
# Delete the old index
r = requests.delete('{base_url}/{index_name}'.format(base_url=base_url, index_name=current_index_name))
r.raise_for_status()

# ------------------------------------------------
# Create an alias (so that on next time this will be easier to do without downtime)
r = requests.post('{base_url}/_aliases'.format(base_url=base_url), json={
    "actions": [
        {"add": {
            "alias": current_index_name,
            "index": new_index_name
        }}
    ]
})
r.raise_for_status()
```

---

### In case you DO ✅ have an aliased index

These are the steps required, no downtime

1. Get current mapping of `StatCateg_v1`
2. Create a new index `StatCateg_v2` with the correct mappings
3. Reindex from `StatCateg_v1` to `StatCateg_v2`
4. Swap aliases (`StatCateg_v1` -> `StatCateg`) with (`StatCateg_v2` -> `StatCateg`)
5. Delete the old index `StatCateg_v1`

**Example snippet (in python):**

```
import requests

index_name = 'StatCateg'
current_index_name = 'StatCateg_v1'
next_index_name = 'StatCateg_v2'
base_url = 'https://...'
mapping_changes = {
    "nom_categorie": {"type": "keyword"}
}

# ------------------------------------------------
# Get current mapping
r = requests.get('{base_url}/{index_name}'.format(base_url=base_url, index_name=current_index_name))
r.raise_for_status()
content = r.json()
mappings = content[current_index_name]['mappings']
mappings['properties'].update(mapping_changes)

# ------------------------------------------------
# Create a new index with the correct mappings
r = requests.put('{base_url}/{index_name}'.format(base_url=base_url, index_name=next_index_name), json={
    'mappings': mappings
})
r.raise_for_status()

# ------------------------------------------------
# Reindex
r = requests.post('{base_url}/_reindex'.format(base_url=base_url), json={
    "source": {
        "index": current_index_name
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": next_index_name
    }
})
r.raise_for_status()

# ------------------------------------------------
# Replace old index alias with new  
r = requests.post('{base_url}/_aliases'.format(base_url=base_url), json={
    "actions": [
        {"remove": {
            "alias": index_name,
            "index": current_index_name
        }},
        {"add": {
            "alias": index_name,
            "index": next_index_name
        }}
    ]
})
r.raise_for_status()

# ------------------------------------------------
# Delete the old index
r = requests.delete('{base_url}/{index_name}'.format(base_url=base_url, index_name=current_index_name))
r.raise_for_status()
```